# How to create two lists from an existing file and compare them to each other?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a file that is separated into four different categories: Level, Char1, Char2, and Years It looks like this:(file continues at the etc.)

```
Level     Char1   Char2   Years

1         Leon    Chris   1990-1999
2         Mario   Luigi   1990-1999
3         Peach   Cloud   1990-1999
4         Leon    Chris   2000-2009
5         Ghost   Garen   2000-2009
6         Mario   Vincent 2000-2009
etc...   etc...   etc..   etc...
```

I want to compare the Char1 and Char2 and print the names that occur in the years 1990-1999 but not in 2000-2009, so for this it would print

```
These names are going away:
Luigi Peach Cloud etc...
```

I am thinking you need to put them either into a list or a dictionary file but I don't know how to separate out the char1 and char2 and compare them to the years. Any help on this would be extremely helpful!

Comment: use `str.split()` to separate the columns :
`"1         Leon    Chris   1990-1999".split()`-->`['1', 'Leon', 'Chris', '1990-1999']`
`

Comment: Are they tab separated?

Comment: They are not tab separated it shows up in the file as this:  1,Leon,Chris,1990-1999

Comment: @user2276168 So it's comma separated?

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND Let's assume so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('test.csv') as f:
        print f.read()


Level,Char1,Char2,Years
1,Leon,Chris,1990-1999
2,Mario,Luigi,1990-1999
3,Peach,Cloud,1990-1999
4,Leon,Chris,2000-2009
5,Ghost,Garen,2000-2009
6,Mario,Vincent,2000-2009
>>> with open('test.csv') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        next(r, None) # skip header

        names = set()
        for level, char1, char2, years in r:
            if years == "1990-1999":
                names += {char1, char2}
            else: # 2000 - 2009
                names -= {char1, char2}
        print "These names are going away"
        print " ".join(names)


These names are going away
Peach Luigi Cloud
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of "which names are on this group and not on this group" is
a job for "sets". Python has then implemented internally - 
so, you just group your data by the date column, and use 
set "subtraction"  - which is the same as 
"elements on this set that are not contained in that
other set" to get your results.

Assuming you have only two, haed coded, data groups, this is all you need:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(set)

with open("myfilename") as file_:
   for line in file_:
      line = line.split()
      if len(line) == 4 and line[0].isdigit():
          data[line[3]].add(line[1])
          data[line[3]].add(line[2])
   print ("These characters are going away:")
   print (" ".join(data["1990-1999"] - data["2000-2009"]))
```

The "defaultdict" is a Python nicety that in this case just save us 2 lines
in the for loop - without it, one would have to add:

```
if line[3] not in data:
    data[line[3]] = set()
```

to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I find that a useful pattern for files like this is to read the data into a dictionary indexed with the header items on the first line. Using that approach, a solution (reading the comma-separated data file from `stdin`) looks like this:

```
import sys

data = {}
hdrLabel = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip().split(",")
for header in hdrLabel:
    data[header] = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    for (i,item) in enumerate(line.rstrip().split(",")):
        data[hdrLabel[i]].append(item)

def getCharSet(cols,yrRange):
    s = set()
    for c in cols:
        s = s | {data[c][i] for i in range(len(data[c])) 
            if data["Years"][i] == yrRange}
    return s

set19 = getCharSet(["Char1","Char2"],"1990-1999")
set20 = getCharSet(["Char1","Char2"],"2000-2009")
print (set19-set20)
```

This approach has the advantage that it allows many different data manipulations after the data are read in, without having to worry about getting column numbers correct, etc.